# What will happen to the not reviewed raised flags?

Tags: support, flags

I got 10 raised flags which are not reviewed yet and marked `active`. What will happen to them?

Comment: Nothing. They will sit there until a moderator handle them, or the flagged post deleted etc.

Comment: ... or until they are reviewed in an appropriate review queue. Depends on the kind of flags you raised. One thing for sure - they won't just expire.

Comment: I got some raised flags since 6 months ago with no attention

Comment: @SuperHornet close flags most likely? With over 10k questions waiting for review, it's taking time.